# Custom pages can only be queried on local host - PagesAPIEndpoint

Tags: django, wagtail

Can somebody tell me why my `api_router.register_endpoint('pages', PagesAPIEndpoint)` can only be queried on `localhost`?

`api_router.register_endpoint('images', ImagesAPIEndpoint)` works either way.

I am trying to figure out the difference between 65 and 1007 because the last number seems a bit arbitrary. Successful attempt on `api/v2/images` is 446

```
curl http://192.168.10.220:8000/api/cms/v2/pages/
{
    "meta": {
        "total_count": 0
    },
    "items": []
}
web_1  | [17/May/2019 05:52:35] "GET /api/cms/v2/pages/ HTTP/1.1" 200 65

curl  http://localhost:8000/api/cms/v2/pages/
{
    "meta": {
        "total_count": 2
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "meta": {
                "type": "cms.ArticlePageIndex",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/cms/v2/pages/4/",
                "html_url": "http://localhost/api/cms/",
                "slug": "article",
                "first_published_at": "2019-05-05T04:43:25.433000Z"
            },
            "title": "article"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "meta": {
                "type": "cms.ArticlePage",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/cms/v2/pages/5/",
                "html_url": "http://localhost/api/cms/txa709-treats-mrsa-infection-and-restores-efficacy-cefdinir/",
                "slug": "txa709-treats-mrsa-infection-and-restores-efficacy-cefdinir",
                "first_published_at": "2019-05-05T05:05:02.483000Z"
            },
            "title": "TXA709 treats MRSA infection and restores efficacy of cefdinir"
        }
    ]
}
web_1  | [17/May/2019 05:52:35] "GET /api/cms/v2/pages/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1007
```

I even added the custom url to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. I should be running a dev build

Edit: For anyone wondering about the fix, gasman is correct about the entry point. However, you also need to set the correct root. I had two bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the correct hostname in the Wagtail admin, under Settings -> Sites. The API will return pages that belong to the current site - i.e. the one matching the hostname in the API request - so if this is set to `localhost`, it will only respond to requests on `localhost`. Alternatively, ticking the 'default site' checkbox should allow it to match on all hostnames.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.